# flutter - infinite loop on a finite array

Tags: firebase, flutter

I don't understand why the result of my code is an infinite loop.

```
class _SearchUserState extends State<SearchUser> {
  List usernames = [];
```

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var invitedBy = widget.snapshot.data()["invitedBy"];
    final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    invitedBy.forEach((userId) async {
      try {
        var snap = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get();
        var username = snap.data()!["username"];
        print(username);
        setState(() {
          usernames.add(username);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        print(err);
      }
    });
```

```
 Text("invitedBy length ${invitedBy.length}"),
        Text("usernames length ${usernames.length}")
```

For the two last lines of code i get :`"invitedBy length 1"` , `"usernames length + infinite number"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `setState` inside your `build` method. That triggers another build, and `setState` is called again, and so on...

Comment: To expand on Kirills answer, which is correct, you shouldn't have any business login in the build method.

Comment: i removed setState but now i can't update the username variable anymore. any suggestions ?

Comment: okay but how can i access widget.snapshot otherwise ? @krumpli

Comment: In the initState() method